# How to remove a single child of a single canvas after I added it?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF project where i have to create a few ellipses on a canvas. I create two check Box and when i check on the first checkbox, the red ellipse will show on the canvas. If i uncheck the first check box, the ellipse will be disappear....the second check box will have the same function by creating a blue ellipse instead.

So heres my situation, when the two checkboxes are checked, a blue and a red ellipse will appear. To clear the ellipse on the canvas, i use the `myCanvas.children.clear()`. But when i uncheck one of the checkbox, both of the ellipse will be deleted.

```
private void redCB_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       drawRedCircle();
    }

private void redCB_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       myCanvas.Children.Clear();
    }

private void blueCB_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       drawBlueCircle();
    }

private void blueCB_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       myCanvas.Children.Clear();
    }

private void drawRedCircle()
    {
        Ellipse myCircle = new Ellipse();
        myCircle.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        myCircle.Width = 30;
        myCircle.Height = 30;
        myCircle.StrokeThickness = 2;

        Canvas.SetLeft(myCircle, 10);
        Canvas.SetRight(myCircle, 10);
        Canvas.SetBottom(myCircle, 10);
        Canvas.SetTop(myCircle, 10);

        myCanvas.Children.Add(myCircle);
    }

 private void drawBlueCircle()
    {
        Ellipse myCircle = new Ellipse();
        myCircle.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
        myCircle.Width = 30;
        myCircle.Height = 30;
        myCircle.StrokeThickness = 2;

        Canvas.SetLeft(myCircle, 20);
        Canvas.SetRight(myCircle, 20);
        Canvas.SetBottom(myCircle, 20);
        Canvas.SetTop(myCircle, 20);

        myCanvas.Children.Add(myCircle);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give the added circle a name, you can find it when the checkbox is unchecked and then remove it pretty easily.

```
private string redCircleName = "redCircle";
private string blueCircleName = "blueCircle";

private void redCB_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    drawRedCircle();
}

private void redCB_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RemoveCircleByName(redCircleName);
}

private void blueCB_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    drawBlueCircle();
}

private void blueCB_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RemoveCircleByName(blueCircleName);
}

private void RemoveCircleByName(string name)
{
    var circle = (UIElement)LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(myCanvas, name);
    myCanvas.Children.Remove(circle);
}

private void drawRedCircle()
{
    Ellipse myCircle = new Ellipse();
    myCircle.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
    myCircle.Width = 30;
    myCircle.Height = 30;
    myCircle.StrokeThickness = 2;

    //Give it a name here so we can find it later
    myCircle.Name = redCircleName;

    Canvas.SetLeft(myCircle, 10);
    Canvas.SetRight(myCircle, 10);
    Canvas.SetBottom(myCircle, 10);
    Canvas.SetTop(myCircle, 10);

    myCanvas.Children.Add(myCircle);
}

private void drawBlueCircle()
{
    Ellipse myCircle = new Ellipse();
    myCircle.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
    myCircle.Width = 30;
    myCircle.Height = 30;
    myCircle.StrokeThickness = 2;

    //Give it a name here so we can find it later
    myCircle.Name = blueCircleName;

    Canvas.SetLeft(myCircle, 20);
    Canvas.SetRight(myCircle, 20);
    Canvas.SetBottom(myCircle, 20);
    Canvas.SetTop(myCircle, 20);

    myCanvas.Children.Add(myCircle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `unchecked` event calls later, which means that the circle created by `checked` event is cleared by the `unchecked` event.

One solution can be to move the logic of creating and clearing circles to a single method, and only registered `checked` events.

```
private void drawCircle()
{
       myCanvas.Children.Clear();

       if(redCB.Checked) drawRedCircle();
       if(blueCB.Checked) drawBlueCircle();     
}

private void redCB_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   drawCircle();
}

private void blueCB_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   drawCircle();
}
```

Comment: In your solution, i cant get 2 ellipse in the same time,right?

Comment: i got error when i tyring to compile it :The event 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.Checked' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=.

Comment: if i change the redCB.Checked to redCB.isChecked == true, it can be run. But the result is not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then add/remove why not using the visibility ( IsVisible) of the ellipse ?  Bind them to a notifying boolean property, and you bind also the checkBox to that property.

```
// ellipse1Visible is a notifying boolean 
Binding ellipseBinding = new Binding("ellipse1Visible");
ellipseBinding .Source = ??? ;   // set your binding source here (? this ?)
myEllipse.SetBinding(Ellipse.IsVisibleProperty, ellipseBinding );
myRelatedCheckBox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, ellipseBinding)
```

if you want to use any number of ellipse, you have to use
an Array/List/ObservableColection of 'notifying booleans'
the syntax is :

```
 // i is a valid index in the ellipseVisible collection of notifying boolean.
 Binding ellipseBinding = new Binding("ellipseVisible[" & i & "]");
 // the rest of the code is the same
```

you can add the checkbox in a near StackPanel/listBox/... while you add the related ellipse in the canvas.

No need to add/remove ellipse and no need to handle checked/unchecked with this solution.

Rq : if you intend to make no use of the visibility of each ellipse, you can even do it in a simpler way : no boolean, but rather you directly bind the visibility to the IsChecked property of the CheckBox :

```
// ... we just created myEllipse and myCheckBox
// ...  and inserted them into canvas/stackPanel 
Binding ellipseBinding = new Binding("IsChecked");
ellipseBinding.Source  = myCheckBox; 
myEllipse.SetBinding(Ellipse.IsVisibleProperty, ellipseBinding);
// and that's all
```