# How to delete objects so that they no longer use processor power

Tags: c#, .net, list, object

Basically, i have an endless number of blocks (each built from class "Enemy") being create, stored into a list, and sent animated across the screen. It does this forever. I want to delete the first block after 100 blocks have been created so as not to use too much processing power. Any ideas?

THIS IS THE CODE FOR THE WHOLE CLASS FOR WHICH THE OBJECTS I WANT TO DELETE:

```
namespace MovementTestV1
 {
class Enemy
{

    protected Dispatcher dispatcher;
    protected Canvas Background;
    protected Label Display;
    Int32 waitTime;
    double EnemyWidth = 53;
    Image EnemyImage;
    String FilePathImage;
    BitmapImage bitPic;
    protected double x, y;
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr;
    double incrementSize = 5.0;
    private int i = 0;

     public Enemy(Canvas Background, Dispatcher dispatcher, Dictionary<String, String> keys,Label Display, Int32 waitTime = 100)
    {
        this.Background = Background;
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
        this.waitTime = 70;
        //this.keys = keys;
        this.Display = Display;

        EnemyImage = new Image();
        EnemyImage.Width = EnemyWidth;

        FilePathImage = @"RedSqare.png";
        bitPic = LoadBitmap(FilePathImage, EnemyWidth);

        //tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        //tmr.Interval = this.waitTime;
        //tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(Position);
        //tmr.Start();

    }
    protected BitmapImage LoadBitmap(String assetsRelativePath, double decodeWidth)
    {
        BitmapImage theBitmap = new BitmapImage();
        theBitmap.BeginInit();
        String basePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"assets\");
        String path = System.IO.Path.Combine(basePath, assetsRelativePath);
        theBitmap.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);
        theBitmap.DecodePixelWidth = (int)decodeWidth;
        theBitmap.EndInit();

        return theBitmap;
    }


    public void Place(double x, double y)
    {

        EnemyImage.Source = bitPic;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        Background.Children.Add(EnemyImage);
        EnemyImage.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x);
        EnemyImage.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y);


        tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        tmr.Interval = 10;
        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(Position);
        tmr.Start();

    }

    public void Position(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {


        i++;

        if (i < 9000)
        {
             x -= incrementSize *.3;

        }

        UpdatePosition();

    }
    void UpdatePosition()
    {

        EnemyImage.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x);
        EnemyImage.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y);
    }


    public double X
    {
        get
        {
            return x;
        }
        set
        {
            x = value;
        }
    }

    public double Y
    {
        get
        {
            return y;
        }
        set
        {
            y = value;
        }
    }

    public void Shutdown()
    {
        tmr.Stop();

    }

}
```

}

```
  public void spawn(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 place = random.Next(1, 4);

        Enemy enemy;
        i += 2;
        if (i % 46 == 0)
        {
            Int32 Ycoord = random.Next(0, 700);
            switch (place)
            {
                case 1:
                    enemy = new Enemy(Background, dispatcher, keys, Display, 10);
                    enemy.Place(1080, Ycoord);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    enemy = new Enemy(Background, dispatcher, keys, Display, 10);
                    enemy.Place(1080, Ycoord);

                    break;
                default:
                    enemy = new Enemy(Background, dispatcher, keys, Display, 10);
                    enemy.Place(1080, Ycoord);
                    break;
            }
            enemies.Add(enemy);
        }
        if (enemies.Count > 5)
        {
          //THIS PART DOESNT WORK!!!!!
            enemies.RemoveAt(0);
            //enemies[1] = 0;
            ////enemies[2] = null;
            //enemies[2].Shutdown();
            ////enemies[3] = null;
            //enemies[3].Shutdown();
            ////enemies[4] = null;
            //enemies[4].Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the `Remove` method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Change the list to a circular array?

Comment: @Matthew i used RemoveAt to no avail

Comment: @groverboy Honestly, i've never heard of a circular array before

Comment: @RyanBrady you just create array of size n and use next and current indexes to iterate and add to it `nextInd = currentInd%sizeOfArray`

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @GuruStron after this code is executed the squares are still on my screen.

Comment: It does sound like a circular array is what you are looking for. To get this affect you could create your block array, say myblockarray = block[100]; Then when you add items insert to an incrementing index mod 100. myblockarray[incrindex % 100] = somenewblock

Comment: @GuruStron could an issue lie the the fact that its being displayed on a canvas?

Comment: objects don't use processing power - they are very green - 0W

Comment: @markmnl they do when they're on a canvas being animated.

Comment: @RyanBrady it seems so

Comment: @RyanBrady how do you animate your objects? from which source you take them when you display them?

Comment: @RyanBrady processing the objects, whatever you are doing whether it be drawing them or counting them, uses processing time!

Comment: @GuroStron look in my enemy class at my "place" function. It places my block on the canvas, then starts a timer so it can move it, which takes place in "position". This is all managed by a master timer in main.

Comment: @markmnl yes you're right, poor wording on my part, but good insight on yours.

Comment: how about setting the object to null before removing it from the list and also adding a IDispose interface to it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx

Comment: @RyanBrady you need to remove your enemy image from background wher removing from `enemies`

Comment: sorry you should dispose it and then set it to null when removing it from the list

Comment: @GuruStron They do yes.

Comment: @chaddienhart i've never really used IDispose before. I really feel like there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: @RyanBrady i think you need to remove corresponding image from `Background.Children` on deleting enemy

Comment: @GuruStron yes, this is what i was starting to come to. You dont know how to remove from a canvas do you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx doesnt really have a clear cut method for it.

Comment: @RyanBrady your canvas has reference to enemy image and timer has reference to enemy movement handler, so they timer holds whole enemy object in memory. You need to remove image fron background and event handler

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413752/how-to-remove-a-single-child-of-a-single-canvas-after-i-added-it) or [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/910dd63c-3846-42b7-bd52-4940d496bbdc/removing-uielements-from-a-canvas)

Comment: @RyanBrady `Canvas.Children` is `UIElementCollection` which has `Remove` and `RemoveAt` methods

Comment: @Gurustron Okay, i'm going to play around with it for awhile, i at least know a direction to go in. One thing i didnt understand is how a timer can hold an object..

Comment: @RyanBrady yes, it is not correct because you create new timer in every enemy object(not sure why though), and a little remark [The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and is limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds. If you require a multithreaded timer with greater accuracy, use the Timer class in the System.Timers namespace.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @GuruStron Okay, thanks for all your help. I dont exactly remember why i use a timer in enemy but i remember that it was necessary for some reason or another, i'll look into getting rid of it after i fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without any code to work off of... However, you could just check to see if your list has over 100 blocks, then setting your first blocks to null. C# has a garbage collector that will clean up the mess.

Edit: or use the Remove method stated above.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); ++i )
{
    if ( enemies.Count > 5 )
    {
        enemies.Remove(i);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well i just posted some code, but the thing is i have set each element of the list to NULL and nothing happened. Same with remove at.